# HTML - reference to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What is the second declaration saying and why is jQuery referenced twice in the HTML?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is checking that jQuery was loaded from the Google CDN.  If it is not it falls back to a local copy of jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

The second line is saying like :

```
if (the google version of jQuery i.e. 1.7.2 is available)
   use it
else
   lets include what we have in local i.e. 1.7.1 .
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like fallback for loading jQuery api from google server, the second script checks if jQuery object is defined, if not it loads jQuery library from site's domain.